# Log system information collected by Monit to local log

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, monit, system-monitoring

I have configured Monit version 5.6 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. There are few check like filesystem usage, remote host connectivity check and service monitoring. 
Now, when I check the web gui of monit, I see something like this;
[image]

Now, there are many parameters that monit shows by default; Load average, CPU, Memory etc. I want all these in a log file so that I can transport the metrics to Elasticsearch.

However, when I check the log file, it shows like this;

[image]

How do I log all the metrics that monit shows on the web gui to the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible out-of-the-box. You could try to "bend" the M/Monit collector feature from the Monit configuration file `set mmonit http://monit:monit@192.168.1.10:8080/collector` to send data to an Elastic search and parse it with an ES filter.
You could either request the HTML page and parse or the same without the output of command `monit status`.